# How to remove commas from numbers string in DataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, formatting, string-formatting

I have a DataGrid that is displaying Customer's phone numbers but the DataGrid is adding in commas to the numbers:

[image]

Its ok if the phone number has spaces in it like the second row but if they enter the number without spaces, then the DataGrid automatically formats the numbers.

Code for DataGrid:

```
   <asp:DataGrid CssClass="tblResults" runat="server" OnItemCreated="dgCRMContacts_ItemCreated" OnItemDataBound="dgCRMContacts_ItemDataBound" ID="dgCRMContacts" DataKeyField="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
   <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" />                        
        <Columns>
              <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="Contact Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
              <asp:BoundColumn DataField="ContactPhone" HeaderText="Phone Number"></asp:BoundColumn>                                            
        </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

`ContactPhone` in the database doesn't contain any commas. It is a type `string`. The commas only get added when the number is displayed on the DataGrid. How do I stop the phone number from automatically formatting?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use method in filds or change data on it you should use templatecolumn such as :

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Principal Office">
   <ItemTemplate>
      <%# replasecoma_method(Eval("pos")) %>
   <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateColumn>
```